# Use compute_driver with libvirt.LibvirtDriver and ironic.IronicDriver in same compute node

Tags: openstack

I am trying to follow the instructions shared https://docs.openstack.org/ironic/latest/install/configure-compute.html

As per the instructions shared, compute_driver
should be ironic.IronicDriver but i would like to have libvirt.LibvirtDriver and ironic.IronicDriver togther in same nova conf. Is there any way i can acheive this?

I am using PackStack for OpenStack.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The nova-compute service with the ironic.IronicDriver enabled is best deployed with the rest of your control plane. This can either be together with the other Ironic service (e.g. ironic-conductor) or with the Nova services (e.g. nova-conductor).

The concept of nova-compute with ironic is drastically different from a regular nova-compute, as it's meant to work more like a proxy between Nova and Ironic.